# Android, using Bitmap (NDK + alpha bytes): i miss something?

Tags: android, android-ndk, alpha

I come from the Qt world and i am porting an application to Android. I am bit confused, i am banging my head for a few days now on something that must be so trivial that i cannot find why it's not working.

Some background: i have a C++ engine which i use trough NDK and JNI. This engine creates some bitmaps and passes them to the Java side, the Java side must display them on a View and let the user interact with them (drag and such).

The engine works properly, because i use it under Qt with full success. This is the workflow:

1- Java loads a big Bitmap from a custom data file (the C++ engine expects it to be in ARGB format, but it's compressed JPG data)

```
Bitmap.Config fmt = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer, 0, size).copy( fmt , false);
```

2- initialize the C++ engine passing the bitmap. The C++ engine "breaks" the bitmap in smaller tiles. For tile it builds a rather complex alpha mask and stores it into the first byte of the bitmap (the "a" byte). This alpha mask only uses two values: 0xFF for opaque and 0x00 for transparent.

```
init_C_engine( this.fullImage );
```

3- The Java side then allocates all the tiles bitmaps, i do in two steps because before init i dont know which size will the tiles be. The engine will populate the tile_width and tile_height arrays:

```
Bitmap.Config fmt = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
for (int t = 0; t < this.puzzle_size; t++ ){
    tile_data[ t ] = Bitmap.createBitmap(  tile_width[t],  tile_height[t],   fmt);
```

4- Last step,inside the C++ engine, all the tiles bitmaps are filled:

```
for ( int n = 0; n < nBitmaps; n++ )
{
        jobject bitmap = env->GetObjectArrayElement( bitmaps, n );
        AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info);
        AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&pixels));
        game->getTileBitmap( n, (unsigned char*)pixels );
        AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
        env->SetObjectArrayElement( bitmaps, n, bitmap );
    }   
}
```

Now, in my custom View:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    for ( int tile = 0; tile < board.nTiles; tile++ ){
            canvas.drawBitmap( tile_data[tile],
                               tile_x[tile],
                               tile_y[tile], paint);
        }
}
```

What i expect is that on my View i see my tiles with transparent areas. what i get instead is a weird behaviour so that on the black background i see the ENTIRE tile like the alpha bytes are all set to opaque, but when i move the tiles one of top of the other, the "transparent" areas get combined in some strange way, like colors are "xor"ed or multiplied in some way! When i move one tile on the other i can see the areas where the alpha bytes are set to transparent but colors gets mangled instead of being transparend!

Basically i expect that pixels having alpha set to 0 are drawn as transparent... i looked on internet but i could not find anything usefull to help me out....

Does somebody have ideas? Anything will be appreciated!
thanks.

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe there's some unwanted filtering ongoing as you're expecting. Take a look on `Paint.setColorFilter` and `PorterDuffColorFilter`. There you get to choose how alpha is handled.

Comment: Unfortunately Android docs are so thin that i cannot understand what setColorFilter does at all... nor how to use it? Do you know of any examples or documentation?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give a proper answer atm but [PorterDuff.Mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html) documentation shows the equations for calculating final color values. And I'm guessing SRC_ATOP is the one you're looking for.

Comment: I dont understand the equations because there is no explanation on what the values are. What is Sa? Sc? Da? Dc?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use the index `t` instead of `tile` inside the for loop inside `onDraw`? Like this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(tile_data[t], tile_x[t], tile_y[t], paint);
```